# Android AppWidget - how to cache my own class?

Tags: android, caching, android-appwidget

I'm working on a `AppWidget` that retrieves a JSON url and displays it. I also show when the widget was last updated with a `TextView` that displays something like "last updated: 9.00am". Note that this should be relative time, that is, I don't want to show "last updated: 27/8/2015 9.00am". If the widget is not updated for one day, it should display "last updated: yesterday".

No problems when internet connection is present, but when it is not I'd like to keep showing previous results and update the "last updated" `TextView`, that is calculate the relative time string between now and when it was last updated. How do I cache this information?

Inspired by [this widget](https://github.com/waynedgrant/android-appwidget-cirrus), I'm using a custom ClientCache.java class

```
import android.util.SparseArray;

public class ClientCache
{
    private static SparseArray<ChannelFeedData> cache = new SparseArray<ChannelFeedData>();

    private ClientCache() {}

    public static void update(int appWidgetId, ChannelFeedData cfd)
    {
        cache.put(appWidgetId, cfd);
    }

    public static ChannelFeedData fetch(int appWidgetId)
    {
        return cache.get(appWidgetId);
    }

    public static void remove(int appWidget)
    {
        cache.remove(appWidget);
    }

    public static boolean isCached(int appWidget)
    {
        return fetch(appWidget) != null;
    }
}
```

My `ChannelFeedData` class includes a method that stores when it was retrieved, but calling `isCached` returns `false` if the widget has died in the meantime.

How can I cache my own class even if my `AppWidget` is killed and restored from time to time by the system?

Comment: You're currently using an in-memory cache. If you wan't to keep your data when your app is killed, you will need a file cache, such as a SQLite database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("pref_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        pref.edit().putString("update_key", "data to be saved");    //save data
        pref.edit().commit();   

        String s = pref.getString("update_key", "empty");       //get data
```